# Dynamically Change pivot table source data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pivot table within an Excel 2010 workbook and the source changes everyday and gets outputed onto another excel workbook with name format as: "filename_MM.DD.YYYY.xlsx"

I have tried the following

```
Set ws1 = Worksheets("GRAPH")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("COC")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("LC")
Dim file_path As String
Dim file_name As String
Dim year As String
Dim day As String
Dim month As String
Dim project As String
Dim full_name As String

file_path = Sheets("Master").Range("F" & rep1).Value
file_name = Sheets("Master").Range("G" & rep1).Value
output_sheet = Sheets("Master").Range("L" & rep1).Value
year = Sheets("Master").Range("M" & rep1).Value
month = Format(Sheets("Master").Range("I" & rep1).Value, "00")
day = Format(Sheets("Master").Range("L" & rep1).Value, "00")
project = Sheets("Master").Range("B1").Value
full_name = Sheets("Master").Range("N10").Value

ws1.Activate

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "\\JLR1GBMDCZZZB5J\SebServer\BOM_CAD_SCRIPT\project\2016\06 \22\full_name BOM'!$D:$CC" _
    , Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
Next rep1
```

So the full_name is the full name of the file, project is the name of the folder and so on. This is all located in a sheet called 'Master' and pulls in the data from there.

But when changing the data source it does not work.

The source will change everyday and will be in a new folder with the new date every day, once a day.

Please Help

Thank you

Comment: You are using Excel 2010, so you need to modify to `Version:= xlPivotTableVersion12)`.  Why are you not using the parameters you entered above, like" `file_path` , `file_name` , `year`, etc. ?  Is the Excel folder source allways equals to today's date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SourceData argument you have in your code is:

```
SourceData:="\\JLR1GBMDCZZZB5J\SebServer\BOM_CAD_SCRIPT\project\2016\06 \22\full_name BOM'!$D:$CC"
```

As this is all contained in `""` you are passing this whole argument as a single string word for word every time you run your code without any change. I can see that within this you have written the names of a couple of your variables in attempt to change this value each time you run your code, in order to achieve this you need to append this like so:

```
SourceData:="\\Start of the filepath\" & aVariableFromYourMacro & "\end of the filepath"
```

in your case you are looking for something like the following:

```
SourceData:="\\JLR1GBMDCZZZB5J\SebServer\BOM_CAD_SCRIPT\" & project & "\" & year & "\" & month & "\" & day & "\" & full_name & " BOM'!$D:$CC"
```

In this example I have placed your variables in where the project, full_name and date labels were in the original string. You may need to modify this to get it to work how you like however hopefully from this example you can understand what you need to do.

Comment: thank you for your response, that is working now but the end refrence where i state the cell range and sheet where i want the Pivot Table to look at is not woring. it tried to put that in the file name. How shall i proceed: `"\\JLR1GBMDCZZZB5J\SebServer\BOM_CAD_SCRIPT\" & project & "\" & year & "\" & month & "\" & day & "\" & file_name & month & "." & day & "." & year & ".xlsx" "BOM'!$D:$CC"  _`

Comment: managed to fix the import but get another issue: `PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "\\JLR1GBMDCZZZB5J\SebServer\BOM_CAD_SCRIPT\" & project & "\" & year & "\" & month & "\" & day & "\" & square1 & file_name & month & "." & day & "." & year & ".xlsx" & square2 & "BOM!$D:$CF" _` it updates the first table but then it fails saying EXCEL has run out of re sources. Help anyone

Comment: @MahadKhan It seems like your code is working as expected, however you have run into a new problem. The 'Excel has run out of resources' is the error created when the application runs out of available memory and is unable to continue processing as there is no 'space' left for it to work in. I would recommend that you create a new question for this problem,  this way you will be more likely to attract people with more experience of this issue and will be more likely able to help you.